# How would you combine 3 MySQL Databases into 1 Database?

Tags: mysql, database

**How would you combine 3 MySQL Databases into 1 Database?**

On the same server I have three (3) individual websites with each site having their own MySQL database:

site1 --> database1, 1 table, 16 fields

site2 --> database2, 1 table, 16 fields

site3 --> database3, 1 table, 16 fields

All three databases have an identical structure where as each database has only 1 table with 16 fields.
In all 3 databases, the table names are the same (Post_Data) and all 16 fields are identical. The index field (field 11) is named Post_Date.

**Each table contains over 1,000,000 entries.**

I am in the process of creating a 4th website with a MySQL database (database4, 1 table, 16 fields) to be used as a search site to perform search queries showing the results from the other 3 database sites. In this 4th website, I am currently running a script that queries all 3 databases individually and combines the results. Then, I remove the duplicates from the results.

I think that this in an inefficient way to perform search queries on all 3 databases. I prefer to query just one database that contains all the information from the other 3 databases minus the duplicates.

**My question is:**

***How would I combine all three database tables from database1, database2, and database3 into a single table within database4?
Also, database4 will need to be updated ever hour with the data from database1, database2, and database3. I could use cron to perform the update.***

I am essentially looking for the PHP / MySQL code to perform this task.

Keep in mind that there will be duplicate entries across all three databases.
In other words, database1, database2, and database3 may all contain some entries that are identical, so I would need to remove the duplicate entries once all 3 database tables are combined into a single table within database4.

Since this 4th website will essentially be a search type site available to any site visitor, I need it to have a fast search response minimizing the load on the server. My current search method (querying on all 3 databases simultaneously and combining the results) affects the server load on all 3 websites for each search query.

**Concerns:**

1. Database4 cannot contain duplicates from database1, database2, and database3.
2. I need the search site to have a fast search response minimizing the load on the server.
3. Database4 needs to be updated ever hour with the data from database1, database2, and database3. I could use cron to perform the update.

I have never created a search type database before. Therefore, would I also need to incorporate an additional search index field in database4?

Comment: Why not just create a view?

Answer (score 0):

Once an hour;

```
> USE database4

> CREATE TABLE temp AS 
     SELECT * FROM database1.Post_Data
     UNION
     SELECT * FROM database2.Post_Data
     UNION
     SELECT * FROM database3.Post_Data

> CREATE INDEX ix_post_date ON temp(Post_Date);

> RENAME TABLE Post_Data TO backup, temp TO Post_Data
```

Of course, if your tables are huge, you may instead want to find a way to timestamp changes so that you can update incrementally.

Comment: Each table contains over 1,000,000 entries. What do you mean by update incrementally? In other words, would'nt I just repeat the same script as you stated above every hour?

Comment: @Sammy What part did not work? Table names are case sensitive, so if the table is not called `Post_Data` cased like that, you may get errors.

Comment: First, thank you for your help. 
I know that table names are case sensitive, but for some reason nothing happened at all. I tried the code you gave me including the CREATE INDEX and RENAME TABLE lines, but no luck. 

I did a repost to find a solution to a modified version of the code you gave me, but so far no valid answers yet. The repost is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888483/trying-to-combine-multiple-database-tables-into-one-table

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson i have multiple database with different no of tables with different no of columns. So how can  i merge these Database in to single database. Without losing single row of data ?