# Trying to combine multiple database tables into one table

Tags: mysql, database, union

For some reason combining multiple tables using the following code does not work. I want to also remove the duplicates, so I assume **UNION** is correct to use and not to use UNION ALL.

How would I combine all three database tables from database1, database2, and database3 into a single table within database4?

All databases tables have identical structures.

```
<?php
 // Variable definitions omitted

       // Connect to all 4 Databases
            $connection1 = mysql_connect($host1, $username1, $password1) or die ('Cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
            $connection2 = mysql_connect($host2, $username2, $password2) or die ('Cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
            $connection3 = mysql_connect($host3, $username3, $password3) or die ('Cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
            $connection4 = mysql_connect($host4, $username4, $password4) or die ('Cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());

       // Merge all 4 Databases into the Search Database 4
            mysql_select_db ($database4);
            mysql_query("
             SELECT * FROM $database4.$TableName4
             UNION
             SELECT * FROM $database1.$TableName1
             UNION
             SELECT * FROM $database2.$TableName2
             UNION
             SELECT * FROM $database3.$TableName3
             ");

       // Close databases connections
            mysql_close($connection1);
            mysql_close($connection2);
            mysql_close($connection3);
            mysql_close($connection4);
?>
```

Comment: There is no way to do it.. You misunderstood the conception of connections, schemas and how mysql works. Simple question for you, could you run it against the database? Or through the command line? I wouldn't say so.

Comment: @medina this did not help, thanks

Comment: @Sammy did you find the solution for merging the databases  into single database ? or can you please share some ideas about this ..?